# error in spring boot while using spring.io demo project

Tags: spring-boot

imported a sample demo project from spring.io. When I run the service I got the below error please help, this error is stopping apache tom cat. Dependency I used is only Web.Below is the log. please help

2018-02-16 11:13:45.976  WARN 7008 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ensure that you have a database driver dependency in your classpath. For example, if you are using Maven, you can use an embedded H2 database by adding the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.191</version>
</dependency>
```

to the `pom.xml` file in the `dependencies` block.